# Getting Terrible Accuracy on CNN Model that I am Basing on a Research Paper: ~ 5%

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am following a [research paper](http://ashokpant.github.io/publications/ashok_2015_deep.pdf), trying to implement their proposed model using Tensorflow and Keras.

Here is the overview of the dataset:

- 92,000 total images of the Devanagari alphabet and numerals

  - 78,200 total training images
  - 13,800 total testing images
- Number of classes: 46

Here is the proposed model in the research paper: [model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AO5tk.png)

And here is my keras implementation of the model:

```
INPUT_SHAPE = (32, 32, 1)

activation = 'relu'
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=4, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation=activation, padding='valid', input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=12, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation=activation, padding='valid'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(256, activation=activation))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(46, activation=activation))

opt = SGD(learning_rate=0.005, momentum=0.9)

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

[my model output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3XsU.png)

And as the paper suggested, I have implemented data augmentation using keras to create my training and validation generators:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

batch_size = 200

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,  # normalization
                                   rotation_range=50,  # rotation
                                   width_shift_range=0.2,  # random crop
                                   height_shift_range=0.2,  # random crop
                                   shear_range=0.8,  # random manipulation
                                   zoom_range=0.2,  # zooming in 
                                   fill_mode='constant',  # to fill with constant padding 
                                   horizontal_flip=True)  # mirroring 

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/content/Dataset/DevanagariHandwrittenCharacterDataset/Train',
        target_size=(32, 32),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        color_mode='grayscale')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/content/Dataset/DevanagariHandwrittenCharacterDataset/Test',
        target_size=(32, 32),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='categorical',
        color_mode='grayscale')
```

Most of the hyperparameters (such as mini-batch size, kernel sizes, filters, optimizer choice, number of epochs, Dropout rate, and strides) were borrowed from the provided paper.

Finally, here is my model fitting code:

```
history = model.fit(
        x=train_generator,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=78200 // batch_size,  
        validation_steps=13800 // batch_size,
        epochs=50)
```

How come my training and validation accuracy metrics be stalled at around 0.05? I suspect that there is/are fundamental mistakes with my implementation or some part that I have overlooked. Can somebody guide me in the right direction with this?

Comment: The output layer should use a softmax activation, not ReLU.

Comment: As @Dr.Snoopy says.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy thanks for your comment! I was planning to use softmax but then noticed this line in the research paper: "The fully connected layers model the input by applying non-linearity like in a traditional feed-forward network. The type of nonlinearity used is ReLU-non linearity." (pg. 3). Anyways, now, I am re-training my network with softmax and the results already look much better!

Comment: @hapakalahdohnut you can apply relu everywhere except for the last classification layer but for the classification layer you have to apply `softmax` or else you have to use the default activation and change your loss function parameter `from_logits=True`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the activation fn in final layer. Use Softmax